# What is the best practice to enrich data when synchronizing data with Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am thinking about solutions to enrich data from Kafka.
Now I am using implementing Mongo Kafka Connect to sync all changes to Kafka. The kafka connect use the change stream to watch oplogs and public changes to Kafka. Relationship between Mongo's collection and Kafka Topic is 1:1.
On the consumer side, when it pulls data, it will get the reference id that we need to join to other collection to get the data.
To join data between collections, I have 2 solutions below.

1. when pulling data by consumers, it need to go back to the Mongo database to fetch or the data or join collections according to the reference key.

   - For this way, I concern about the number of connects that I need to go back to the Mongo database.
2. using kafka streaming to join data among topics.

   - For the second solution, I like to know how to keep that master data in the topics forever and how to maintain records in topics like db tables, so each row have unique index, and when data changes come to the topic, we can update the records.

If you have any other solutions, please let me know.

Comment: Seems to me that the second option looks like having compacted Kafka topics with unlimited retention. Here is a brief and interesting article about it https://docs.aiven.io/docs/products/kafka/concepts/log-compaction.html

Answer (score 2):

Your consumer can do whatever it wants. You may need to increase various Kafka timeout configs depending on your database lookups, though.

Kafka topics can be infinitely retained with `retention.ms=-1`, or by compaction. When you use compaction, it'll act similarly to a KV store (but as a log). To get an actual lookup store, you can build a KTable, then join a topic stream against it

This page covers various join patterns in Kafka Streams - https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/joins/

You can also use ksqlDB